# Converting between time formats

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert time from the `year_month_day-hh_mm_ss` to timestapm (in milliseconds since 1971) with DateUtils? or some other library..

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into the Python [`datetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Python datetime and time modules.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime("2017_03_16-14:08:10", "%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S")
```

This will create a datetime object of d

Then use mktime from Python's time module to get your timestamp

```
import time
time.mktime(d.timetuple())*1000
```

The `*1000` is required to convert from seconds to milliseconds.

Also, do you mean 1971 or the Unix epoch (Jan 01 1970)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the arrow module found at the following URL:                   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the time with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then you can get the time since epoch time in milliseconds by using strftime to format only seconds. Multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

```
converted_time.strftime("%s") * 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
year = timedelta(days=(2017-1971)*365)#number of days from 1971 to 2017
mili_sec = (year.total_seconds())*1000#you will get total_seconds just mulitply with 1000 to get milliseconds
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1450656000000.0
```

## OR

You wanted difference from a particular date.Ex from **1971-01-01 to 2017-03-16-14:08:10**

```
from datetime import datetime
new_day = datetime.strptime("2017_03_16-14:08:10", "%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S")
old_day = datetime.strptime("1971_01_01-00:00:00", "%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S")
diff_day_milliseconds = ((new_day - old_day).total_seconds())*1000
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1458137290000.0
```